# Train from Oslo airport to Drammen

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, airport-transfer, oslo

I'm flying into Oslo airport on Monday 4th August, landing around 3 pm. I need to get to Drammen by train. Where do I buy a ticket and is it easy? Also any advice on platforms etc is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you mean Oslo Airport, Gardermoen?  There's also Oslo Airport, Torp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one of the following trains:

- R10 regional train towards Drammen;
- R11 regional train towards Skien, or;
- L12 suburban train towards Kongsberg.

These trains normally leave from platform 4, and the ticket price is NOK 221.
It takes one hour to Drammen.

Comment: @Tony If this answer satisfies you, please upvote it and accept it by pressing the button below the down arrow